# Set timeout for web service request in apache cxf

Tags: java, apache, web-services, http, soap

I am working on the integration testcases, as part of that different testcase i have set http timeout for a request means i would like to issue the http request to server but timeout should happen from client side before it receives the request. Since i am using CXF,  i have changed as according the solution provided in official site,
 [How to configure the HTTPConduit for the SOAP Client?](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html)

I already a question exists,
[changing client timeout for a particular request in Apache CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979933/changing-client-timeout-for-a-particular-request-in-apache-cxf)

My problem,
I have java classes generated from cxf codegen plugin, where a interface is generated which has all the soap web service operations.

```
    URL wsdl = getClass().getResource("wsdl/CustomerService_1.wsdl");
    QName serviceName = new QName("srv.retail.app:ws:customer:1", "CustomerService_1");
    QName portName =
            new QName("srv.retail.app:ws:customer:1", "CustomerService_1PortTypeSoap11");
    CustomerService_1 service = new CustomerService_1(wsdl, serviceName);
    CustomerService1PortType customerServicePortType = service.getPort(portName, CustomerService1PortType.class);

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(customerServicePortType);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();

    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(300);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

Tried different ways those are not working, will be great if you give inputs on this.

Comment: can't you change the generated java code and redeploy? If yes, then just follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979933/changing-client-timeout-for-a-particular-request-in-apache-cxf

Comment: i can do that but i will not be having control on the timeout, if i do programatically then we have we have conditions and activate thats why looking for java solutions.